# How to fetch google wallet tickets in android?

Tags: android, google-pay

I am trying to fetch the tickets list in my Google Wallet tickets

> Integrate the Google Wallet API to digitize passes on Android: Adding the "Add to Google Wallet" button
> https://codelabs.developers.google.com/add-to-wallet-android#3

I did not find any Google Wallet API or SDK to fetch the tickets list in my Google Wallet tickets

Could anyone plz share a reference link regarding my question
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As of 8/31/22** there currently is no capability to query for available tickets in the Android Wallet SDK.

The only current availability is to save passes to wallet in the Google Wallet Android SDK.